# Map with path-dependent value type?

Tags: scala, dictionary, path-dependent-type

I know that Scala has path-dependent types, so for example if I have a class within an inner class I can constrain one argument of a method to be an instance of the inner class of the other argument:

```
class Outer { class Inner( x:Int ) }
val o1 = new Outer
val o2 = new Outer
val i11 = new o1.Inner(11)
val i12 = new o1.Inner(12)
val i21 = new o2.Inner(21)
def f[ A <: Outer ]( a:A )( i:a.Inner ) = (a,i)
f(o1)(i11)  // works
f(o1)(i21)  // type mismatch; i21 is from o2, not o1
```

And I can create a Map from an Outer to an Inner using a type projection:

```
var m = Map[Outer,Outer#Inner]()
```

But that would allow entries like `o1 -> i21`, and I don't want that to be allowed. Is there any type magic to require that a value be an instance of its key's inner class? That is, I want to say something like

```
var m = Map[Outer,$1.Inner]()  // this doesn't work, of course
```

Comment: The way you phrased the question: "require that the value be an instance of the key's inner class" already describes your `var m = Map[Outer,Outer#Inner]()`

Comment: Defining the map with a type projection like that requires that the value be an instance of *some* Outer's Inner, but not the Outer that was used for they key.

Comment: `def g[A <: Outer] = Map.empty[A, A#Inner]`

Comment: I don't think the type system is going to help you here (unless you go the route of something like Shapeless's `HMap`), but you can always police what gets added to the map.

Comment: You'd need a new, more constrained `Map` type or arbitrary dependent types in Scala. The former you can write as a safe wrapper around the existing `Map`. You'd basically have it be parametrized only by the key type, with a constraint that the key have some named inner type, and then your accessor methods would have types like `def get(k: K): k.Inner`. It wouldn't implement the current Scala collection generic map traits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Path dependent types are scoped to an object instance, as in the example you gave:

```
def f[ A <: Outer ]( a:A )( i:a.Inner ) = (a,i)
```

Here the path-dependent type relies on the object reference "a", which is in scope for the declaration of the second parameter list.

The [map definition](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map) looks a bit like:

```
trait Map[A,+B] {
  def get(key: A): Option[B]
  def + [B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1)): This
}
```

There is no object of type `A` in scope here for you to reference when defining `B`.

As others have hinted, you could define a new similar Map class which fits this requirement:

```
trait Map2[A <: Outer] {
  def get(key: A): Option[key.Inner]
  def put(key: A)(value: key.Inner): this.type
}
```

Comment: Travis and Dan actually answered the question for me via comments almost a year and a half ago, but for future readers it's nice to have an actual answer that explains things more clearly, so I'll accept this as the answer, Rich.