# Python typing: concrete class that implements protocol with method that takes another protocol as argument

Tags: python, protocols, repository-pattern, typing

I'm trying to get the typing correct for the following example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

from typing_extensions import Protocol


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Animal(Protocol):
    age: int


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Cat:
    age: int


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Dog:
    age: int


class AnimalRepository(Protocol):
    def get(self, animals: list[Animal]) -> None:
        ...


class CatRepository:
    def get(self, animals: list[Cat]) -> None:
        pass


class DogRepository:
    def get(self, animals: list[Dog]) -> None:
        pass


ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP: dict[type[Animal], AnimalRepository] = {
    Cat: CatRepository(),
    Dog: DogRepository(),
}
```

This results in the following problem:

```
Expression of type "dict[type[Cat] | type[Dog], CatRepository | DogRepository]" cannot be assigned to declared type "dict[type[Animal], AnimalRepository]"
  "CatRepository" is incompatible with protocol "AnimalRepository"
    "get" is an incompatible type
      Type "(animals: list[Cat]) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(animals: list[Animal]) -> None"
        Parameter 1: type "list[Animal]" cannot be assigned to type "list[Cat]"
          "list[Animal]" is incompatible with "list[Cat]"
  "DogRepository" is incompatible with protocol "AnimalRepository"
    "get" is an incompatible type
      Type "(animals: list[Dog]) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(animals: list[Animal]) -> None"
```

So the specific repositories don't properly implement the `AnimalRepository` as I'm using the implementations of the `Animal` protocol, i.e., `Cat`, `Dog`, rather than the protocol itself.

Am I able to resolve this issue while keeping the same structure?

I suspect this is related to a Liskov Substitution Principle issue but I'm not familiar enough to know how to handle this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Attempted using generics and type variables without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your `CatRepository` and `DogRepository` do not satisfy `AnimalRepository`. Taking a look at `CatRepository`, it has the following method.

```
def get(self, animals: list[Cat]) -> None:
```

But `AnimalRepository` expects a method that takes a `list[Animal]`, not a `list[Cat]`. `AnimalRepository` says "I can take a list of *any* animal and do something", but your method only works with cats, not all animals.

You can change `AnimalRepository` to be generic.

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Animal)

class AnimalRepository(Protocol[T]):
    def get(self, animals: list[T]) -> None:
        ...
```

Now `CatRepository` satisfies `AnimalRepository[Cat]` and `DogRepository` satisfies `AnimalRepository[Dog]`. Those types don't have anything in common, since they accept different arguments, but at least all of the code is in the same place.

There's no way to type your `ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP`, unfortunately. What you're looking for is a *path-dependent map*. That is, you want a map for which the type of the value depends on the value of the key. That's wildly complicated to implement. We could do it in a dependently-typed proof language like Agda, and it's [sort-of possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295159/implementing-path-dependent-map-types-in-shapeless) in a language with an insanely powerful type system like Scala (with Shapeless). But Python's type hinting is a fairly simple system, from a type theory perspective.

Here's what I recommend. You have a good idea for an interface. You want a way to give a type of `Animal` and get an `AnimalRepository[T]` where `T` is that type. We can write this type in Python, but we just can't prove the function implementation is correct. So I recommend using `class AnimalRepository(Protocol[T])` as defined above. Then define your `ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP` with `Any` typing.

```
_ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP: dict[type[Animal], Any] = {
    Cat: CatRepository(),
    Dog: DogRepository(),
}
```

Note that I prefix this with an underscore, since we don't want to export it. This dictionary is now an implementation detail.

Now expose it with a function that casts the type problems away.

```
def get_animal_repository(animal_type: type[T]) -> AnimalRepository[T]:
    if animal_type in _ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP:
        # Note: The Any type happily casts to whatever we want.
        return _ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP[animal_type]
    else:
        # Your choice what to do in the case of an invalid animal.
        ...
```

The implementation of this function definitely cheats with `Any`. But callers, and anyone external to your module, still sees a nice type-safe API.

Comment: Thanks very much @silvio! Helpful and informative. Appreciated the extra background.

Comment: You could use `_ANIMAL_TYPE_REPOSITORY_MAP: dict[type[Animal], AnimalRepository[Any]]`: it's still `Any`, but not so cruel (you know it's still an `AnimalRepository` anyway, this info can help future readers - they may see this type hint in their IDE). It should still work in `get_animal_repository`.